# What's the best practice for Magento dependencies?

Tags: magento-1.8, adminhtml, dependency

## Synopsis

I have a question regarding the best practices with Magento dependencies. Essentially I have a custom module that overrides `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController` this currently works providing I include the Magento core class prior to extending (generally what you'd expect).

My code looks something along the lines of:

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Catalog/ProductController.php';

class Vendor_Module_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{
    // My things go here.
}
```

My question is simply to understand if theres a *nicer* method of including core classes for overriding (see example)?

**Example**

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Adminhtml') . DS . 'Catalog/ProductController.php';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Controllers, there is no nicer way unfortunately, you need to use `require_once` or something like that. You should replace all occurences of `/` with `DS` though (one `/` is still in your sample code).

If you are overriding Models, Blocks or Helpers, you won't need it, as the overwritten classes get autoloaded.

Comment: Your response appears most accurate, it is a shame but then again I suppose there is no further *logical* way of doing the inclusion now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of overriding a core controller class

In your custom modules config.xml file put the following code.

```
<config>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <Vendor_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Vendor_Module_Adminhtml</Vendor_Module >
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>
    </config>
```

Then the your controller class will be like this.

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php';
class Vendor_Module_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
    extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController
{

// your code

}
```